# Google Map referer-not-allowed-map-error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, api-key

I'm facing a problem with the new update of google map, after generating the key I need to add the URLs which contain google map, there are some URLs contain IDs so how can I add it to display the map?
`WebsiteUrl/OrderDetails/{OrderId}`

Thanks in Advance.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyCzz.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the HTTP referrer in this way WebsiteUrl/OrderDetails/*